# What is the best modern day, Hebrew kitzur sefer for learning hilchos succah?

Tags: halacha, product-recommendation, jewish-books, sukkah

I am looking for something in the style of ספר ארחות שבת. That is, something that has short introductions to each subsection in which the author will explain the relevant background from the gemaras and rishonim, and then goes on to explain the svoros in footnotes relating to each halacha he quotes according to the rishonim, gemaras, and poskim.
Does anyone know if something like this exists (in Hebrew) for hilchos succah?

I also would be interested in this style of sefer for hilchos Rosh HaShana, yom kippur, pesach, etc. I specifically want Hebrew, as I find it is then easier to go back to shulchan aruch once I'm used to the Hebrew terms and have the conceptual framework built.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) John and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 3):

Welcome to Mi Yodeya. I think the sefer [Peninei Halakha](https://www.sefaria.org/Peninei_Halakhah,_Sukkot) may be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Hilchos Chag BeChag by Rav Moshe Mordechai Karp Shlit'a.